# arrays java:90 (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Then i do this code:

```
 private int[] getAmplitude(byte[] fft) {
        int[] amplitude = new int[fft.length/2-2] ;
        for (int i = 2; i <= fft.length/2-2;i+= 2) {
            for(int j=0;j<= fft.length/2-2;j++){
            amplitude[j]=(fft[i] * fft[i] + fft[i + 1] * fft[i + 1]);}
        }
        return amplitude;
```

i got this:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.astroplayerbeta.gui.eq.EqVisualizerCaptureAudio.getAmplitude(EqVisualizerCaptureAudio.java:90)
    at com.astroplayerbeta.gui.eq.EqVisualizerCaptureAudio.onFftDataCapture(EqVisualizerCaptureAudio.java:67)
    at android.media.audiofx.Visualizer$NativeEventHandler.handleMessage(Visualizer.java:484)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

That is my trouble?

fft[] array got 1024 length.

Comment: Your trouble is: **which line is line number 90**? How should we know? All your lines deal with the arrays, so it could be any of them. Please at least provide reasonable information about your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say `fft.length/2-2` is 3. then amplitude is an array of size 3.

Now you say

```
for(int j=0;j<= fft.length/2-2;j++){
    amplitude[j]=(fft[i] * fft[i] + fft[i + 1] * fft[i + 1]);
}
```

If I were to write that in english it would be: for j = 0 to 3 put somthing in amplitude[j]. so you are putting **4** values into amplitude, which is an array of size 3. and so you are getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Change the lines to

```
for(int j=0;j< fft.length/2-2;j++){
    amplitude[j]=(fft[i] * fft[i] + fft[i + 1] * fft[i + 1]);
}
```

(the <= changed to <) and you should be set.

Note that you also have a similar problem with fft and its for-loop.

Comment: but fft got 1024 length, how i get array with length 3? it must be 510?

Comment: @Bel its a simplified example to show you what your bug is.. also,  you never mentioned the size of fft in your original question :)